# swift: MongoDB Realm is not syncing to mobile

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

when the app is opened I try to sync the cloud data to the app using this function

```
  struct AppRootView: View {
@State var homeLink = false // <- add here
@State var loginLink = false
@State private var selection: String? = nil


var body: some View {
    NavigationView { // <- wrap in the `NavigationView`
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("App")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            NavigationLink(destination: homeMainView(), tag: "home", selection: $selection) {EmptyView()}
            NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), tag: "login", selection: $selection) {EmptyView()}
        }

    }
    .onAppear(perform: handleSignIn)
    .frame(minWidth: 0,
           maxWidth: .infinity,
           minHeight: 0,
           maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.yellow)
}

func handleSignIn() {
     print("HANDLING SIGNING IN")
    if let _ = app.currentUser() {
        print("USER IS LOGGED IN ALREADY")
        self.handleRealmSync()

        self.selection = "home" // <- activate the `NavigationLink`
    } else {
        print("USER NEEDS TO LOGIN")
        self.selection = "login"
        print("not logged in; present sign in/signup view")
    }
}

func handleRealmSync(){
    let user = app.currentUser()
    let partitionValue = "store=walmart"

    Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: user!.configuration(partitionValue: partitionValue),

        callback: { (maybeRealm, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)")
            }
            guard let realm = maybeRealm else {
                fatalError("realm is nil!")
            }
            // realm opened
            print("Realm SYNC IS OPENED")
        })
   }
   }
```

and I get the print out that "Realm SYNC IS OPENED" but I began to notice that when I query with this code

```
 itemrealm = try! Realm(configuration: user.configuration(partitionValue: partitioningValue)

 storeitems = self.itemrealm.objects(Item.self)
```

the query is not getting all that i have in the cloud cluster.

I guess sync was working well before until I imported more data to the cloud. I currently have atleast 10,000 data in my cluster that are given the partion value being called then I did a .count on storeitems and notice its only pulling about 4,000 items (which is the amount before I imported new data). So the cloud is not syncing the current data.

I then checked my dashboard log and saw this

[image]

a clicked on the permission error show this message

> Error Type: Sync -> SyncSession End
> Error:
> Ending session with error: user does not have write access to partition for schema instructions (ProtocolErrorCode=206)

my sync permission is

```
 Read : true
 Write : {
   "%%partition": "%%user.id"
  }
```

Users can read all data but can only write their own data

How can I fix the permission error and sync my latest cluster to the mobile client?

when I switched the write permission to

```
  "%%user.id": "%%partition"
```

this is the error i got

> Fatal error: Failed to open realm: Error Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=208 "Bad client file identifier (IDENT)" UserInfo={Category=realm::sync::ProtocolError, NSLocalizedDescription=Bad client file identifier (IDENT), Error Code=208}:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your write permissions are backwards.

instead of this (from the question)

```
Read : true
Write : {
   "%%partition": "%%user.id"
}
```

do this

```
Read : true
Write : {
   "%%user.id": "%%partition"
}
```

The info comes from the MongoDB Realm Sync Documentation [Define Sync Rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/rules/#define-read-write-permissions)

Comment: The write persmission was generated by MongoDB Realm. I tried what you suggested but the app crashed and threw an error. the question is updated with the error message

Comment: I updated the question with my AppRootView and the error message.

Comment: @learner101 I updated my answer with a link to the documentation showing the correct format for the permissions (as shown in my answer). Your crash could be due to a number of things but it will take a bit of troubleshooting on your part to identify the cause. I would suggest updating the question or maybe even asking a different question since the permission error is one issue and the crash is another. Please ensure you include the code that's crashing and any other details about it, including the line its crashing on.

Comment: thank you Jay. This is another one of some of the confusions in their documentations.